# Showing button from previous fragment in new one (Android)

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have strange issue. I want to open new Fragment from current Fragment.
So I do it like this :

```
    Fragment fragment = new teamSettings();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.teamDetailAdmin, fragment);
    // add to backstack, then back button will be work with fragments!
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    // add animation
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    ft.commit();
```

The problem is, that in my new fragment I see those button which I clicked in previous fragment.

[image] [image]

Can anyone explain, why this happens ?

Comment: Can you share your fragments xmls ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try this way,

Please take framelayout in your current activity

 <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

Fragment fragment = new teamSettings();
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment, 
fragment.getTag()).commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling FragmentTransition `replace(R.id.container,fragment)` works pretty much as calling `remove` to every fragment of the given container, and `add` to the new fragment. If your previous fragment is not being removed (with the Button still showing), that's because you added that fragment for a container other than `R.id.teamDetailAdmin`. To successfully replace the fragment, if they are in different containers, you need to remove the current fragment from it's container, and add the new fragment to the container you wish.