# Showing button of previous fragment in new one

Tags: java, android

I try to open a new Fragment from current Fragment. But when I do this I'm faced with a problem, the button from the previous fragment is not going back to the new fragment

I did [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46521979/showing-button-from-previous-fragment-in-new-one-android) but it is not so beneficial for me

**Fragment COntainer xml**

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container_navbar"
    class="com.example.poplify.baby_guru_sample.Bottom_Tabs.Paytab_frag"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_385sdp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_2sdp"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_2sdp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/toolbar1"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.97" />
```

Replacing first fragment to second

```
  final Fragment fragment = new Reff_code_frag();
    fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    reff_code.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container_navbar,fragment).addToBackStack("Paytab_frag").commit();

        }
    });
```

BottomNavbar Code

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navlistener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        Fragment selectFrag=null;

        switch (menuItem.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.tab1:
                selectFrag = new Paytab_frag();
                break;

            case R.id.tab2 :
                selectFrag = new Add_child_tab_frag();
                    break;

            case R.id.tab3:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"tab3",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     break;

             case R.id.tab4:
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"tab4",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
        }
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container_navbar,selectFrag).commit();
        return true;
    }
};
```

xml of first fragment

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/dark_grey"
tools:context=".Bottom_Tabs.Paytab_frag">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_214sdp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_8sdp"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
    android:layout_marginTop="128dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/_4sdp"
    android:text="@string/Paytxt1"
    android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline6"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.531"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline5"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline4" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/amt_txt"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_150sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_8sdp"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_with_border"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"

    android:hint="Enter Amount"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline6"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.516"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline5"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_214sdp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_8sdp"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/paytxt2"
    android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline6"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.531"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline5"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/amt_txt" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ref_code_txt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_8sdp"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:text="@string/refe_link"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline6"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.51"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline5"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/pay_btn"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_215sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_8sdp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_8sdp"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_backgrond"
    android:text="@string/pay"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textSize="@dimen/_18sdp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline6"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.545"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline5"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ref_code_txt"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.04000002" />
```

Second Fragment

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/frag_background"

tools:context=".Bottom_Tabs.Reff_code_frag">



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="76dp"

    android:text="@string/enter_ref"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline16"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.47"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline15"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ref_code_txt"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_150sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_with_border"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:hint="@string/ref_txt_hint"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline16"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline15"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:text="@string/ref_code"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline16"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.48"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline15"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ref_code_txt" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/apply_btn"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_215sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_backgrond"
    android:text="@string/apply"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline16"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.486"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline15"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/cancel_btn"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_215sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"

    android:text="@string/cancel"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:background="@drawable/button_with_border"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline16"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.486"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline15"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/apply_btn"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.164" />
```

Comment: Do you want to go from second fragment to first fragment ? Or is there a issue with your "PAY" button visible in second fragment ?

Comment: @Umar Hussain Pay button visible in second fragment

Comment: Show the code how are you setting the button in first fragment? Or the complete xml of your activity and first fragment and second fragment.

Comment: @UmarHussain i modified my question .

Comment: @RahulChaudhary Actually your first fragment is not replaced, because you are adding the first fragment statically in XML, and then replacing it with the second fragment dynamically using FragmentTransactionManager, but You cannot replace a fragment defined statically in the layout file. You can only replace fragments that you added dynamically via a FragmentTransaction, So What You need to do is add the first fragment to FragmentTransactionManager in container dynamically.

Comment: @akashzincle Thanks for Answer!!!... i tried it but it still show same ... I shared my code where i replace fragments